# how to remove [*] from filename using powershell

Tags: powershell, shell

I tried below script but it skips [anything]

```
$rootDirectory = "C:\Path\To\Your\Root\Directory"

Get-ChildItem -Path $rootDirectory -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $newName = $_.Name -replace '[\[\]]', ''
    
    if ($newName -ne $_.Name) {
        $newPath = Join-Path -Path $_.Directory.FullName -ChildPath $newName
        Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $newName -Force
        Write-Host "Renamed $($_.FullName) to $newPath"
    }
}
```

please help me

Answer (score 3):

**Preface**:

- The following shows ***recommended practices* for renaming files efficiently in PowerShell**.
- It's not obvious what your specific problem is: the title mentions removal of `[*]`, but your own attempt seems to want remove the `[` and `]` characters only, which the streamlined solution below does too. See the bottom section for alternative interpretations.

---

```bash
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $rootDirectory -File -Recurse |
  Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '[][]' } -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: **`-WhatIf`** in the command above ***previews* the operation**. Remove it and re-execute once you're sure the operation will do what you want.  You may then add **`-Verbose`** to print each renamed item's full path.</sup>

Note:

- The above uses a **[delay-bind script block](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters)** both for concision and efficiency, i.e. pipe [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) output *directly* to [`Rename-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item) and pass a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`) that performs the name transformation to the latter's `-NewName` parameter:

  - Inside the script block, each [`[System.IO.FileInfo]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo) instance output is available via the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_).
  - The script block's *output* must be the new file *name* only (it is by definition renamed *in place*)<sup>[1]</sup>; use `$_.Name` to get the existing name including the filename extension, or `$_.BaseName` and `$_.Extension` to get the base name and extension separately.
- The **[`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#-whatif)** *previews* the operation; remove it and re-execute the command once you have verified that the operation will work as intended.
- When not using `-WhatIf`, you may use the **[common `-Verbose` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-verbose)** to make `Rename-Item` print the full path of the renamed item to the verbose [output stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams). (That is, you then don't need a `Write-Host` call to do that.)
- `-replace '[][]'` is a streamlined version of your `-replace '[\[\]]', ''` operation; it effectively removes any instances of `[` and `]` from your input file names, so that, for instance, `foo[bar].txt` becomes `foobar.txt`.
- Due to use of **`-File`** to restrict renaming *files*:

  - If the `-replace` operation has no effect, i.e. if the input file name doesn't contain `[` or `]`, the rename operation is a *benign no-op*, so the above is safe to use. In other words: **files that don't match the pattern of interest are simply left alone**.
  - Unfortunately, however, this **would *not* work with *directories*** (if you either omit `-File` and subdirectories are present or if you use `-Directory` to process directories only), as of PowerShell (Core) **7.3.x**:

    - You'd get an *error* for (pointlessly) trying to rename a directory to its existing name, so you'd have to filter out directories with non-matching names in a pipeline segment before the `Rename-Item` call (if you simply ignored or silenced the errors with `-ErrorAction Ignore`, you'd need to make sure that you're not also ignoring *legitimate* errors).
    - [GitHub issue #14903](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77338063/how-to-remove-from-filename-using-powershell/77338107#77338107) is a green-lit suggestion to fix this unfortunate asymmetry, but no one has stepped up to implement it so far.

---

**Alternative interpretations of your renaming intent**:

- If you meant to remove *any substring enclosed in `[…]`* from your file names:

  ```bash
  $Name -replace '\[.*?\]'
  ```

  - Example:

    ```bash
    # -> 'foo.txt'
    'foo[anything-here].txt' -replace '\[.*?\]'
    ```
- If you meant to remove *verbatim* `[*]` from your file names (this would only apply to *Unix*-like platforms, given that Windows doesn't allow verbatim `*` in file names):

  ```bash
  $Name -replace '\[\*\]'
  ```

  - Example:

    ```bash
    # -> 'foo.txt'
    'foo[*].txt' -replace '\[.*?\]'
    ```

---

<sup>[1] To *move* (while possibly also renaming) items, use the [`Move-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/move-item) cmdlet.</sup>

Comment: thanks for your effort, really appreciate it, i just used a python script and solved the issue.

Comment: I'm glad to hear you appreciate the effort, @shasabbir, but why did you resort to Python, given that you asked a PowerShell question and this is a PowerShell solution. Does it not work as expected?

Comment: after getting your answer I was curious and I tried, and it didn't work unfortunately. maybe I did something wrong.

Comment: @shasabbir, given that this solution is likely shorter than a Python solution, you may want to find out _why_ it didn't work. To that end you'll have to provide specific feedback, however. Please see my update (preface and bottom section).